# Individual operations on coordinates in 2D arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Im working on a problem with projectile motion in computational physics, and I want to perform different mathematical operations on the x and y coordinates in my array. The code Im struggling with is indexing inside a for loop.

I've tried different forms for indexing but keep getting errors like "could not broadcast input array from shape (2,2) into shape (2)" and "setting an array element with a sequence."

```
g = 9.81
theta = 30

dt = 0.1
t = 5

n = int(t/dt)
t = zeros(n)
r = zeros((n, 2), float)
v = zeros((n, 2), float)
a = zeros((n, 2), float)

r[0] = array([0,0])
v[0] = array([10*cos(theta), 10*sin(theta)])
t[0] = 0

for i in range(n-1):
    v[i+1] = v[0] - g*dt
    r[i+1] = r[i] + v[i]*dt 
    t[i+1] = t[i] + dt
```

The inserted code shows two columns (v[x,y] and r[x,y]) with different values, where only the y coordinate is correct. This is because the x coordinate is supposed to be constant. I don't understand how to make the x coordinate constant, and only do the operation on the y coordinate. I want the result to be calculated as:

```
v[i+1] = v[0]         # x-coordinate
v[i+1] = v[0] - g*dt  # y-coordinate
```

Comment: In which line you get the error the code is running without error for me. Also it seems that you are using ```from numpy import *``` to import numpy which is not good practice

Comment: The code is running without error but are showing the operation v[0] - g*dt on both coordinates. I want it to be executed on only the y-coordinate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to only index the y part like this

```py
v[i+1, 1] = v[i,1] - g*dt
```